# Set a private value in Azure Pipeline and integrate with TestCafe

Tags: javascript, automation, azure-pipelines

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57ZuA.png)

I have done for create variable group with variable, and also in file yaml for config pipeline, i have defined with thí

```html
variables:
- group: automation-regression
- name:  testcafe
  value: '${USER_PASSWORD}'

steps:
     - task: PowerShell@2
       inputs:
            targetType: "inline"
            script: echo ${testcafe}
                    echo ${USER_PASSWORD}
```

but when start running pipeline regression can not echo the value of testcafe